# Call function based on instance type not working as I expect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance, polymorphism

## Problem

---

Currently I'm trying to write some inventory system. The inventory contains several items. The functionality of each item will changed based on the dog it's used on. Most of the time this means it will do nothing, but specific dogs can use specific items.

I figured I would write a base `Item` class that implements a generic `use(Dog dog)` function. Then if a specific item wants to apply a certain functionality for a dog, it could override the function with a more specific dog type. For example `TennisBall : Item` has a `use(GoldenRetriever dog)`. However, having written this it appears as if only the parent function is ever called.

In my `Inventory` class I have a reference to the dog based on the `Dog` class. When I log what the type of this `Dog` is, I get `GoldenRetriever`. Yet still the parent `Item.use()` function is called instead of the more concrete `TennisBall.use()` function. The reason for this is probably that `Dog` is what the instance is cast to, so it will call that (not quite sure why my `Debug.Log` still shows `GoldenRetriever` then).

I've tried specifying some interfaces to solve the problem also, but it seems that the problem persists. My feeling is that this rather has to do with the parameters in the methods than with anything else.

## Question

---

How can I define functions for my derived classes so they are called based on the type of the provided instance? Do I *have* to cast my instance to a specific type? I find this unintuitive since C# already seems to know what the type of the instance is.

## Code

---

Inventory:

```
public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour {
    ...
    
    private List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
    private Dog dog;
    public int activeItem = 0;

    ...

    public void addItem(Item item) {        
        items.Add(item);  // This is where the TennisBall item will be added
    }

    public void open(Dog dog) {
        open();
        this.dog = dog;
    }

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) {
            Debug.Log(dog);  // Output: Golden Retriever (GoldenRetriever)
            items[activeItem].use(dog);
        }
    }
}
```

Item:

```
public class Item : MonoBehaviour {
    public void use(Dog dog) {
        Debug.Log(dog);  // Still Golden Retriever (GoldenRetriever)
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

TennisBall:

```
public class TennisBall : Item {
    public void use(GoldenRetriever dog) {
        Debug.Log("Doing something specifically for a Golden Retriever!");  // This never gets called
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all `use(Dog dog)` is not a [generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods) function.

Comment: Second `TennisBall.use(GoldenRetriever dog)` is not an override of `Item.use(Dog dog)` it is completely different function with completely different [signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods#method-signatures)

Answer (score 1):

You can start with actually [overriding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override) the `use` function and using some [type-testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast) in the override:

```
public class Item : MonoBehaviour {
    public vitual void use(Dog dog) {
        Debug.Log(dog);  // Still Golden Retriever (GoldenRetriever)
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class TennisBall : Item {
    public override void use(Dog dog) {
         var goldenRetriever = dog as GoldenRetriever; // check if dog is of type GoldenRetriever
         if(goldenRetriever != null)
         {
              Debug.Log("Doing something specifically for a Golden Retriever!");  // This never gets called
         }
         // your other logic....       
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha yes, I guess that makes sense. I was just hoping I would not have to do something like `dog as GoldenRetriever`. I.e. if I now have `GermanShepard` I would have to do not so nice looking if-statements in this function. I would rather have some method overloading in that case if that makes sense.

Comment: @Bono you can use `switch` [expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) or [statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#type-pattern) to prettify those `if`'s in some cases.

Comment: Hmm, I had a look at the generic method link you shared, but it seems what I'm trying to do is not the way I imagined it. I think I might switch this around then. Make a `useTennisBall` function for `Dog` and implement it in `GoldenRetriever`. Then just figure out the method name by seeing what instance the `Item` is and using reflection to call the right function on the `Dog` instance.

Comment: @Bono not fully following why do you need reflection here, TBH.

Comment: I've tried it out and it work, but just does not make sense semantically (i.e. it makes sense for an item to have a `use()` function, not so much a dog with `useTennisBall` I guess). The reason why I don't think the solution you provided is very nice (even though it definitely works and is arguable easier to follow), is that if I have 20 dogs that can use an item this switch/if-statement stuff becomes very cluttered. I would prefer to be able to somehow separate it up into functions per dog/item.

Comment: @Bono if you have different logic per each (or almost each) combination item-dog-function then you will need to perform this mapping somewhere. You can try creating some kind of dictionary to handle this but not sure that it will be much cleaner/easier solution.

Comment: @Bono Also semantically `items.use(dog)` does not look right =)